# After updating bind from 9.8 to 9.12, it does not start anymore with dnssec-validation auto

Tags: bind, gentoo

I used bind 9.8 on gentoo for monthes. After updating the system, bind is now at 9.12.3_p4 but it does not start anymore unless I comment dnssec-validation auto.

I get nothing in named.log.

I get this in message.log :

```
Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: obtaining root key for view _default from '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: obtaining root key for view _default from '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: /etc/bind/bind.keys:28: ignoring managed key for '.': no crypto support
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: root key not loaded
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: loading configuration: failure
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 named[29268]: exiting (due to fatal error)
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 /etc/init.d/named[29266]: start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/sbin/named'
    Jun 27 17:08:16 ns3079610 /etc/init.d/named[29242]: ERROR: named failed to start
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 'no crypto support' sounds like you missed a compile option.

Comment: Thanks, Gerald, I missed this point. I added ssl in uses clauses and I recompiled bind. It works like a charm. I think old bind versions have ssl enabled by default cause I never needed to explicitly set ssl uses clause.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, so you can accept it and mark the question as solved. I'll expand it later regarding the use flags when I'm not on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> no crypto support

sounds like you missed a compile option.

Run `emerge --info | grep ^USE`. You should find `ssl` in there. If not, [you have to add it](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/USE):

Open */etc/portage/make.conf* with an editor.

Add `ssl` to the `USE` variable:

```
USE="ldap ssl"
```

Recompile the package:

```
emerge bind
```

Now you should be able to start it.

Comment: `I'll expand it later` +1 when you expand this. Now it solves the problem, but is not really useful as an answer for anyone seeing it in the future.